# Solutions to equation

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\alpha(n)$ be the number of pairs $(x, y)$ of integers such that $x+y = n, 0 \le y \le x$, and let $\beta(n)$ be the number of triples $(x, y, z)$ such that $x + y + z = n$ and $0 \le z \le y \le x.$ Find a simple relation between $\alpha(n)$ and the integer part of the number $\frac{n+2}{2}$ and the relation among $\beta(n), \beta(n -3)$ and $\alpha(n).$

**Attempt:**

We see that $\alpha(n) = \dfrac{\binom{n+1}{1}}{2} = \dfrac{n+1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd and $\alpha(n) = \dfrac{\binom{n+1}{1}-1}{2}+1 = \dfrac{n+2}{2}$ if $n$ is even. Thus, $\alpha(n) = \left[\dfrac{n+2}{2}\right]$.

How do I relate $\beta(n), \beta(n -3)$ and $\alpha(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The triples that satisfy your condition are of two types. Type 1 are the triples with smallest element $0$, and Type 2 are the ones with smallest element $\ge 1$.

There are just as many triples of Type 1 with sum $n$ as there are pairs $(y,x)$  with $0\le y\le x$ such that $y+x=n$.

There are just as many triples of Type 2 with sum $n$ as there are triples $0\le z'\le y'\le x'$ with sum $n-3$. For let $z'=z-1$, $y'=y-1$, and $x'=x-1$. That gives a bijection between the Type 2 triples with sum $n$ and all good triples with sum $n-3$.

Thus we obtain the recurrence
$$\beta(n)=\alpha(n)+\beta(n-3).$$

Comment: It says to obtain a recurrence with $\alpha(n)$ and not $\alpha(n-1)$. Can this be fixed?

Comment: You can express (somewhat awkwardly) $\alpha(n-1)$ in terms of $\alpha(n)$. They are equal when $n$ is odd, and differ by $1$ if $n$ is even. But the natural relationship is with $\alpha(n-1)$. Or else we dump $\alpha(n-1)$ and replace it by $\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: How would we evaluate $\beta(n)$ here as a function of the residue of $n$ modulo $6$?

Comment: The recurrence can be solved. I recall that someone gave a generating function approach to the solution, in one of your earlier questions on the subject. There are other ways of doing basically the same thing.

Comment: Do you know of an easy way of getting $\beta(n)$ as a function of the residue of $n$ modulo $6$?

Comment: My answer would be similar to the one I saw, though I would not use generating functions, but that is basically a matter of style.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. What about the case the smallest element is $0$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: You are right, I was confusing your problem with the very closely related problem of partitions into $k$ parts, where $0$ is not allowed. Easy fix, minor change needed only, and now we get $\alpha(n)$.

Comment: It can be further deduced that $\beta(n) = n+\beta(n-6)$. Is it easy to find $\beta(n)$ in terms of the residue of $n$ modulo $6$ from here?

Comment: I think so. Need to think about it when I have time. If I find an alternate approach I will add it to the solution that has already been given.

Comment: If $n=6k$, then $\beta(n)=3k^2+3k+1$. This can be obtained from your recurrence above, by induction. For $\beta(6(k+1))=6(k+1)+3k^2+3k+1$, and this is $3(k+1)^2+3(k+1)+1$. I can get similar equations for the other $5$ congruence classes.

Comment: So if $m$ is the residue of $n$ modulo $6$ and $n = 6k+m$, we have $\beta(n) = 3k^2+(3+m)k+\beta(m)$. Does that answer the question?

Comment: I can if you wish do the calculation for any other congruence class you pick. All six congruence classes give a quadratic that begins with $3k^2$.

Comment: I am saying that if $m$ is the residue of $n$ modulo $6$ and $n = 6k+m$, we have $\beta(n) = 3k^2+(3+m)k+\beta(m)$ answers the other question I asked, right? It is a function of the residue, $m$, and also $k$.

Comment: I would rather do them one at a time, and then see whether there is a shortcut formula.

Comment: I checked. Your expression gives the right answer for all congruence classes.